# Resolve freezing in react while making calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity, web3js

I am trying to set a spinner while my react app makes a few calls. I am writing a Dapp with web3 and solidity. While making calls to my smart contract I try to set state to show a spinner, but the whole app freezes while the calls to the contract are being made, after calls are made and values returned it sets the spinner and unsets the spinner real fast (you can see the value change console logging the boolean). The app unfreezes and proceeds. How can I get the spinner to set and the app not to freeze while the calls are made:

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // inProcessOfCalling sh
    this.setState({ inProcessOfCalling: true });
    ...
    const contractData = callContract(parseTestJson.steps, web3);
    Promise.all(contractData).then((values) => {
        ...
        // turn spinner off
        this.setState({ inProcessOfCalling: false });
    });
}

function callContract(callInfo, web3) {
    const dataArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < callInfo.length; i += 1) {
        // ...
        const getData = thisContract[callInfo[i].func].getData(
            ...callInfo[i].args,
            { from: callInfo[i].from },
        );
        // ...
        const trans = web3.eth.sendTransaction({
          to: callInfo[i].contract,
          from: callInfo[i].from,
          data: getData,
        });
        let receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(trans);
        returnObj = {
          receipt,
          testName: callInfo[i].name,
          expectPassed: callInfo[i].expects.success === transactionPassed,
          expectMessage: callInfo[i].expects.message,
        };
        dataArr.push({ error: false, returnObj });
    }
    return dataArr;
}
```

I dont think this is a web3 issue. I would assume it would freeze the app with making any multiple fetch calls to APIs.

Comment: are getting receipt  or trans  response

Comment: and make sure that dataArr is a Promise array

Comment: Yeah, i get a receipt and trans. `dataArray` is resolved in my `Promise.all` and I am able to get the data out of my array just fine after that. Its just during the calls I am frozen

Answer (score 0):

You are already calling the `callContract` function which is heavy and the request here <- this is the one causing the `hang`

`const contractData = callContract(parseTestJson.steps, web3);`
it is already called before you put it into a Promise.all

and `contractData` is not a Promise at all, what you can do is return a Promise object inside that function like this

```js
function callContract(callInfo, web3) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const dataArr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < callInfo.length; i += 1) {
        // ...
        const getData = thisContract[callInfo[i].func].getData(
          ...callInfo[i].args, {
            from: callInfo[i].from
          },
        );
        // ...
        const trans = web3.eth.sendTransaction({
          to: callInfo[i].contract,
          from: callInfo[i].from,
          data: getData,
        });
        let receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(trans);
        returnObj = {
          receipt,
          testName: callInfo[i].name,
          expectPassed: callInfo[i].expects.success === transactionPassed,
          expectMessage: callInfo[i].expects.message,
        };
        dataArr.push({
          error: false,
          returnObj
        });
      }
      resolve(dataArr);
    }
  }
```

Learn more about promise here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise